# Daemon app OneDrive file download

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've created a daemon app to access the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve information about a drive item we need to download via a script run from Cron but am unable to download the file contents as the download URL returns a 401 response.

Process for granting the token to access the API is followed from here https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only and the application created has the permission "Have full access to user files".

I can successfully run the request used to get the file information:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/items/{item_id}
```

But calling the download endpoint fails with the 401 response

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/items/{item_id}/content
```

The URI it redirects to and returns in "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl" is formatted as:

```
https://{tenant_id}.sharepoint.com/personal/{user_id}/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=XXX&access_token=XXX
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue between the authenticated context for the graph.microsoft.com resource and {tenant_id}.sharepoint.com. We've added the read/write user files permissions on both APIs in the app.

Comment: This scenario is not officially supported. You'll need to use the SharePoint API directly to download files from SharePoint via app-only authentication. We're working to enable this scenario in the future via Microsoft Graph. Can you tell me more about what you're trying to accomplish that requires app-only permissions, so I can add it to our plan?

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know. We have a spreadsheet owned by a user that we need to download each night and import the data via a script run from cron. We do this currently via Google drive but the business I'm working with is moving everything over to Office 365.